# Which Authentication Policy is Stronger in ADFS?

Tags: adfs2.0

ADFS support below authentication policy

- Windows based Authentication
- Form Based Authentication
- Certificate Based Authentication

Which Authentication Policy is Stronger in ADFS ?

If all policies are set which authentication will be given first priority ? Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged as ADFS 2.0 so I assume you are using that.

Good writeup [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/adfs-2.0/ee895365%28v%3Dmsdn.10%29).

You can set the order in "localAuthenticationTypes".

By default, on the extranet (via WAP) it's Forms as it's non-domain joined so no WIA.

By default, on the intranet, it's WIA as it's domain-joined and providing the browser is configured to support WIA.